# Debug JavaScript in IntelliJ

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I have a grunt project and ran it with command in one terminal

```
grunt server
```

Now I added JavaScript debug configuration in IntelliJ with the URL 
    `localhost:8080/abc?x=y&a=b`

I have added JetBrains IDE support extension as well.

Now when my server is up, I launch my debug configuration (say jsDebug) and Chrome is launched and that's what I get:

[image]

Ques 1 : my URL is

```
localhost:8080/abc?x=y&a=b
```

but in browser it is

```
chrome-extension://hmhgeddbohgjknpmjagkdomcpobmllji/loading.html?url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080/abc?x=y&a=b
```

Ques 2 : It's not loading properly and not stopping at breakpoints.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: this URL just indicates that the debugger is not yet attached - once application is loaded and debugger attached, it will change to `localhost:8080`. What is written in debugger console? I'd suggest creating a support ticket - the problem is likely application-specific and can hardly be resolved on stackoverflow

Comment: nothing in console.
Some time back, i was getting logs in debugger console but it was not stopping at breakpoint.

I don't know what i changed that Its not at all running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.
There was some port issues. 
So I changed port at two places :

1. In the extension(JetBrains) -> options.
2. Debug port in IntelliJ 
   and they must be same.